# Getting user from userId in database Jnit Test

Tags: java, junit

So I'm trying to create a test that would check if the user Id from my method is equal to the same in the database. I have this:

```
@Test
public void testGetUserbyUserId() {
    System.out.println("getUserbyUserId");
    int UserId = 30;
    UserDao instance = new UserDao();
    Users user = instance.getUserbyUserId(UserId);
    Users expResult = user;

    //assertNotNull(expResult);
    Users result = instance.getUserbyUserId(user.getUserId());
    assertEquals(expResult, result);

}
```

Whenever i run this the test fails and in says the user objects are not the same. How can i get the same result and how can i make this test better ? thank you

Comment: Did you override equals()  in Users class?

Comment: no i didn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell java, how to compare 2 different instances of User. E.g. add following method to your User implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherUser) {
    if(otherUser instanceof User)
        return ((User) otherUser).getUserId() == getUserId();
    else
        return false;
};
```

Or lazily;

```
assertEquals(expResult.getUserId(), result.getUserId());
```

Comment: yea thought i had overridden the equals method thanks